# Send e-mail after entityform submission using field from referncing node

Tags: rules, entities

I have a content type called contact page and several entity forms. The content type contact page has two fields on it one entityreference field that is used to reference an entityform and the other a text field used to store an e-mail address.

If the user selects an entity form then when the contact page is rendered so is the referenced entityform. When a user submits and entityform I would like to send an email to the email address supplied on the contact page.

I've been looking at rules but I am struggling to find out where I can load fields from the referencing entity so that I can use the email address on the contact page once an entityform is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to add a condition "this entity has the field". Then you will be able to access this field in the selector in other condition.

[image: Rules condition]